# Is Fragment an Activity? (Android)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

Is Fragment an Activity? and what is difference between fragment and FragmentActivity?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Fragment is not an Activity.
Fragments are hosted inside a FragmentActivity.

Check PJL's answer for more information.

Answer (score 3):

See [Android Developers page on Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html)

Answer (score 0):

In Android an `Activity` can contain several `Fragments` inside. Each *Fragment* can be considered a **View Controller**. Android allows you include ***child Fragment*** inside ***parent Fragment***.

When `Activity` is running, you can manipulate each `Fragment` independently, such as add or remove them.

**Developer's documentation**:

> A `fragment` must always be hosted in an activity and the fragment's lifecycle is directly affected by the host activity's lifecycle. For example, when the activity is paused, so are all fragments in it, and when the activity is destroyed, so are all fragments.